# Android calendar event duration (API)

Tags: android, api, events, calendar, duration

why duration column in calendar Evens table does not get value set via provider?

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
if(allDay==1) {
    long days = (dtend - dtstart + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS - 1) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
    event.put("duration", "P" + days + "D");
} else {
    event.put("duration", "P" + ((dtend-dtstart)/DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS) + "S");
}
Uri eventsUri =Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events")
cr.insert(eventsUri, event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not dividing by zero?
The `DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS` might get zero as value and then it will not perform the calculation (it should crash I presume).

You might want to check it out. I'm no Android programmer, but that's the first thing I would check assuming the code has a valid syntax.